# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '2' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, dotenv

I am using  google spreadsheet as a CMS for my React app. I have the required credentials from google developer console saved in a dotenv file. But the `REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY` is causing this error.
The App works perfectly when I hardcode the `PRIVATE_KEY` value in my `handleSubmit` function .
Please Help(PS if anybody needs any other file please let me know)

dotenv

```
REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n*********\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
REACT_APP_CLIENT_EMAIL=**********.gserviceaccount.com
REACT_APP_SHEET_ID=*********
```

handleSubmit function

```
const handleSubmit=async (e)=>{
        const doc =new GoogleSpreadsheet(process.env.REACT_APP_SHEET_ID);
        console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY)
        console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_EMAIL)
        await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
            client_email:process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_EMAIL,
            private_key: process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY        
        });
      
      
        await doc.loadInfo(); 
        const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
        await sheet.addRow({Website:website,Password:password})
        window.location.reload();
   }
```

Here is the screenshot of the error console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn06T.jpg

EDIT-1
parseKeys index.js

```
var asn1 = require('./asn1')
var aesid = require('./aesid.json')
var fixProc = require('./fixProc')
var ciphers = require('browserify-aes')
var compat = require('pbkdf2')
var Buffer = require('safe-buffer').Buffer
module.exports = parseKeys

function parseKeys (buffer) {
  var password
  if (typeof buffer === 'object' && !Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) {
    password = buffer.passphrase
    buffer = buffer.key
  }
  if (typeof buffer === 'string') {
    buffer = Buffer.from(buffer)
  }

  var stripped = fixProc(buffer, password) ///<=line 19

  var type = stripped.tag
  var data = stripped.data
  var subtype, ndata
  switch (type) {
    case 'CERTIFICATE':
      ndata = asn1.certificate.decode(data, 'der').tbsCertificate.subjectPublicKeyInfo
      // falls through
    case 'PUBLIC KEY':
      if (!ndata) {
        ndata = asn1.PublicKey.decode(data, 'der')
      }
      subtype = ndata.algorithm.algorithm.join('.')
      switch (subtype) {
        case '1.2.840.113549.1.1.1':
          return asn1.RSAPublicKey.decode(ndata.subjectPublicKey.data, 'der')
        case '1.2.840.10045.2.1':
          ndata.subjectPrivateKey = ndata.subjectPublicKey
          return {
            type: 'ec',
            data: ndata
          }
        case '1.2.840.10040.4.1':
          ndata.algorithm.params.pub_key = asn1.DSAparam.decode(ndata.subjectPublicKey.data, 'der')
          return {
            type: 'dsa',
            data: ndata.algorithm.params
          }
        default: throw new Error('unknown key id ' + subtype)
      }
      // throw new Error('unknown key type ' + type)
    case 'ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY':
      data = asn1.EncryptedPrivateKey.decode(data, 'der')
      data = decrypt(data, password)
      // falls through
    case 'PRIVATE KEY':
      ndata = asn1.PrivateKey.decode(data, 'der')
      subtype = ndata.algorithm.algorithm.join('.')
      switch (subtype) {
        case '1.2.840.113549.1.1.1':
          return asn1.RSAPrivateKey.decode(ndata.subjectPrivateKey, 'der')
        case '1.2.840.10045.2.1':
          return {
            curve: ndata.algorithm.curve,
            privateKey: asn1.ECPrivateKey.decode(ndata.subjectPrivateKey, 'der').privateKey
          }
        case '1.2.840.10040.4.1':
          ndata.algorithm.params.priv_key = asn1.DSAparam.decode(ndata.subjectPrivateKey, 'der')
          return {
            type: 'dsa',
            params: ndata.algorithm.params
          }
        default: throw new Error('unknown key id ' + subtype)
      }
      // throw new Error('unknown key type ' + type)
    case 'RSA PUBLIC KEY':
      return asn1.RSAPublicKey.decode(data, 'der')
    case 'RSA PRIVATE KEY':
      return asn1.RSAPrivateKey.decode(data, 'der')
    case 'DSA PRIVATE KEY':
      return {
        type: 'dsa',
        params: asn1.DSAPrivateKey.decode(data, 'der')
      }
    case 'EC PRIVATE KEY':
      data = asn1.ECPrivateKey.decode(data, 'der')
      return {
        curve: data.parameters.value,
        privateKey: data.privateKey
      }
    default: throw new Error('unknown key type ' + type)
  }
}
parseKeys.signature = asn1.signature
function decrypt (data, password) {
  var salt = data.algorithm.decrypt.kde.kdeparams.salt
  var iters = parseInt(data.algorithm.decrypt.kde.kdeparams.iters.toString(), 10)
  var algo = aesid[data.algorithm.decrypt.cipher.algo.join('.')]
  var iv = data.algorithm.decrypt.cipher.iv
  var cipherText = data.subjectPrivateKey
  var keylen = parseInt(algo.split('-')[1], 10) / 8
  var key = compat.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iters, keylen, 'sha1')
  var cipher = ciphers.createDecipheriv(algo, key, iv)
  var out = []
  out.push(cipher.update(cipherText))
  out.push(cipher.final())
  return Buffer.concat(out)
}
```

EDIT-2
fixproc.js

```
// adapted from https://github.com/apatil/pemstrip
var findProc = /Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED[\n\r]+DEK-Info: AES-((?:128)|(?:192)|(?:256))-CBC,([0-9A-H]+)[\n\r]+([0-9A-z\n\r+/=]+)[\n\r]+/m
var startRegex = /^-----BEGIN ((?:.*? KEY)|CERTIFICATE)-----/m
var fullRegex = /^-----BEGIN ((?:.*? KEY)|CERTIFICATE)-----([0-9A-z\n\r+/=]+)-----END \1-----$/m
var evp = require('evp_bytestokey')
var ciphers = require('browserify-aes')
var Buffer = require('safe-buffer').Buffer
module.exports = function (okey, password) {
  var key = okey.toString()
  var match = key.match(findProc)
  var decrypted
  if (!match) {
    var match2 = key.match(fullRegex)
    decrypted = Buffer.from(match2[2].replace(/[\r\n]/g, ''), 'base64') //<=line14
  } else {
    var suite = 'aes' + match[1]
    var iv = Buffer.from(match[2], 'hex')
    var cipherText = Buffer.from(match[3].replace(/[\r\n]/g, ''), 'base64')
    var cipherKey = evp(password, iv.slice(0, 8), parseInt(match[1], 10)).key
    var out = []
    var cipher = ciphers.createDecipheriv(suite, cipherKey, iv)
    out.push(cipher.update(cipherText))
    out.push(cipher.final())
    decrypted = Buffer.concat(out)
  }
  var tag = key.match(startRegex)[1]
  return {
    tag: tag,
    data: decrypted
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your .env file is not configured correctly.

Comment: that's why process.env is undefined

Comment: what's in parseKeys at line 19? could you upload code or smthg pls?

Comment: @Arfanali Maybe but there is no issue with process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_EMAIL, and SHEET_ID
,

Comment: @EzequielS.Sandoval I have uploaded the parseKeys index file

Comment: Add `fixProc.js` too, pls! Your Image says that everything starts in line 14, just to have more context, if u're so kind!

Comment: @EzequielS.Sandoval i gottu mate(well u r the one helping me:)

Comment: Given that your app works when you hardcoded the `PRIVATE_KEY` and the error code says its started from `fixProc.js:14`, this indicates that the issue could be on how you parse the content of your dotenv and not on Google Sheets. Kindly remove the tag for `google-sheets` and `google-sheets-api` as it doesn't seems to be cause of the issue.

Comment: As the error says `cannot read property '2' of null` this tells you that `match2` is null or doesn't have value, so what you're doing here is accesing key 2 of an object: `match = { '2': val }` but instead of this, `match2` seems to be empy, you can verify adding a `debugger;`  at the beginning of your fixProc function expression and seeing what you're doing step by step. Just open devtools while executing this to go into the debugger.
See if line 13 is returning what you want or is returning `null` (i think this is the case)

Comment: @EzequielS.Sandoval thnx for the help man i'll try it

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you accomplished it :) (y)

Answer (score 0):

try to hash your private key into base64 string, then put the hashed value in the env file and when using, decode it. This is the safer way to store private keys